# Angular route not loading the html file

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working in develop a route in Angular application. in fact I've already implemented 3 routes, but one in specifically is not working at all.

I have 3 folders that I want to redirect the html according to the option chosen. So I have created in Angular the folder courses and I have created the code below

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { CoursesDetailComponent } from './courses-detail/courses-detail.component';
import { CoursesComponent } from './courses/courses.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path : '', redirectTo: '/courses', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path : 'courses', component: CoursesComponent},
  {path : "/courses/:id", component: CoursesDetailComponent}
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

All of those path works perfectly except for the last one that when I save the it in the code the browse show nothing..

The code I have created related to the information about the courses is:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-courses',
  templateUrl: './courses.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./courses.component.css']
})
export class CoursesComponent implements OnInit {
  
  courses = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'Angular'},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'React'},
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'MongoDB'},
    {'id': 4, 'name': 'Ruby'},
    {'id': 5, 'name': 'Bootstrap'},
  ];

  constructor(private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) { }


  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onSelect(courses: any){
    this.router.navigate(['/courses', courses.id]);
  }

}
```

I'm not able to identify the issue when I add the line below the code is able to compile but nothing appear in the browse.

```
{path : "/courses/:id", component: CoursesDetailComponent}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `AppRoutingModule` remove the first `/` in the `path` property, it should be like the following

```
{path : "courses/:id", component: CoursesDetailComponent}
```

Also remove it in your `onSelect()` method, it should look like this

```
onSelect(courses: any){
    this.router.navigate(['courses', courses.id]);
}
```